# Can't select column I used in join-on statement

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join, ora-00904

I'm modifying an SQL query so it will be database agnostic (and therefore also would work in SQL Server). This means I have replaced a join-using with a join-on. This worked, but when I placed that sub-query back into its parent I get an error.

I am getting an `ORA-00904: study_event_id: invalid identifier` error on the `SELECT` of a column I used in the `ON` statement of the `JOIN`.

The code below is stripped down a lot to the minimum where I get the error, so the subqueries and aliases need to be preserved as much as possible.

```
SELECT
    study_event_id
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    ea.*,
                    sbj.subject_id
                FROM
                    v_study_event ea,
                    v_subject     sbj
            ) lefttable
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    v_subject_current_event_status
            ) righttable ON righttable.study_event_id = lefttable.study_event_id
        
    ) tbl
```

I can select every other column, but the column I joined on can't be identified.

The column does appear when I SELECT *.

I have tried to specify it with all the above aliases: tbl, lefttable and righttable.

I just don't understand why that one column can't be selected.

In the full query this column is selected with a bunch more, and there are two columns in the join-on statement The other column also can't be selected, but I don't need that one further in the complete query.

Comment: *"I'm modifying a PLSQL query so it works in SQL Server."* ... *"I am getting a ORA-00904: study_event_id"* Huh? That's an Oracle Error, not a SQL Server error. If you're translating a PL/SQL query into T-SQL you'd get a SQL Server error. Unless you are, for some reason, trying to run T-SQL in Oracle? That won't work.

Comment: My language is a bit unclear. We're trying to move from Oracle to SQL Server, so a bunch of queries need to be rewritten as T-SQL doesn't accept the implicit USING on joins. We're trying to find a common ground where the query itself is useable in both languages.

Comment: So you *aren't* trying to modify your query to run in SQL Server, you've trying to make your query database agnositic. Why are you using derived tables like that? Why not just `LEFT JOIN` to the tables?

Comment: The first subquery of the join has a where statement in it, the second one only selects a few columns. 
It is a monster query which was written ages ago, and has been pasted new clauses in. 
So I dont know why, but I can try to simplify it.

Comment: *"The first subquery of the join has a where statement in it"* No it doesn't, there's not a single `WHERE` in your query.

Comment: In the full query it has, but the WHERE doesn't change me not being able to select STUDY_EVENT_ID.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for sample data for your tables; a query that is representative of your problem (if `WHERE` clauses prevent refactoring then include `WHERE` clauses in your example); and the expected output for that sample data. It is very difficult to provide an answer to a question when it has been simplified to a state where the question no longer represents the actual problem because it may have been simplified too far (and also when you don't provide a [MRE] that allows us to replicate the problem).

Comment: So give us a *meaningful* example, not an obfuscated query, which makes no sense using derived tables, @Basje313 . Create an [mre].

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT ea.*,
       sbj.subject_id
FROM   v_study_event ea,
       v_subject     sbj
```

Is the same as:

```sql
SELECT ea.*,
       sbj.subject_id
FROM   v_study_event ea
       CROSS JOIN v_subject sbj
```

and:

```sql
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM   v_subject_current_event_status
) righttable
```

Is the same as:

```sql
LEFT OUTER JOIN v_subject_current_event_status righttable
```

And:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   ( ... ) tbl
```

Does nothing and can be omitted.

Your query can be simplified to (although its not clear which columns you want in the `SELECT` clause):

```sql
SELECT se.*,
       s.subject_id,
       sces.study_event_id
FROM   v_study_event se
       CROSS JOIN v_subject s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN v_subject_current_event_status sces
       ON sces.study_event_id = se.study_event_id
```

If you want to add `WHERE` filters then either:

1. Add them to the end of the query as normal; or
2. If you want to filter `v_subject_current_event_status` before joining then add the filters to the `ON` clause of the join.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed. It seems the first `select *` gets confused.
I had to write out all columns I needed from the joined views.

The columns study_event_id needed to be specified to lefttable.study_event_id.

This query worked:

```
SELECT
    study_event_id
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            lefttable.study_event_id study_event_id
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    ea.*,
                    sbj.subject_id
                FROM
                    v_study_event ea,
                    v_subject     sbj
            ) lefttable
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    v_subject_current_event_status
            ) righttable ON righttable.study_event_id = lefttable.study_event_id
        
    ) tbl
```